# Does bigquery supporting foreign language loading from google sheet

Tags: google-bigquery, create-table

I am new to `bigquery` and I am trying to create a table from google sheet.

I use schema auto detect and in advance option : `header rows to skip 1`

The column header is not in english and I got and error as :

> Failed to create table Duplicate column name '_______'

Comment: unicode is not allowed for identifiers - names that are associated with columns, tables, and other database objects. while data itself is not restricted

Comment: Hi Olivier, did you manage to sort this out? As per [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#identifiers) you could try to enclose the column name by backtick (`) characters to create quoted identifiers. Quoted identifiers can contain any character, such as spaces or symbols.

Comment: @SergiMuñoz , no I did not.
when i try to use backtick in select sentence ,  I still got an error.

SELECT string_field_0 as `s@` from
 query failed :
Invalid field name "s@". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Even with numbers, I got error msg  :
SELECT string_field_0 as `123` from